# Override a method of another class using Java Reflections

Tags: java, class, reflection, annotations, overriding

I have a Java Project where I have 2 classes. I need to use Java reflections to first print the default values as set by the constructor in `ProjectAccount.java` from `mywork.java` class and then I need to Override the `toString()` method to pass values from `mywork.java` class and print them.

I was able to use java reflections to print the default constructor-set values. But I am getting an error when trying to override and print the `toString()` method with arguments.

**ProjectAccount.java**

```
package relive;

public class ProjectAccount {
    private String projectAccountID;
    private double budget;
    public int noOfProjects;

    public ProjectAccount(){
        this.projectAccountID = "MARTINDAWS-BillAnalyzer-001";
        this.budget = 120000.00;
        this.noOfProjects = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Project Accoutn ID = " + projectAccountID + " , Project Budget = "+budget + " , No of Projects = "+ noOfProjects;
    }
}
```

**mywork.java**

```
package relive;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class mywork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("relive.ProjectAccount");
            Constructor<?> constr = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(null);
            Method mets = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("toString", null);
            Object obj = constr.newInstance(new Object[] {});

            //Print Default values
            System.out.println(mets.invoke(obj, null));

            String mod_projectAccountID="ORPT-BT-EMP-DEV";
            double mod_budget = 2200000.0;
            int mod_noOfProjects = 20;

            //Print new passed values using the overridden method
            System.out.println(mets.invoke(obj, mod_projectAccountID,mod_budget, mod_noOfProjects));        
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static String toString(String mod_projectAccountID, double mod_budget, int mod_noOfProjects){
        return "Project Accoutn ID = " + mod_projectAccountID + " , Project Budget = "+mod_budget + " , No of Projects = "+ mod_noOfProjects; 
    }

}
```

**Output and Error**

[image: output]

I guess that I am encountering this error since I have not overridden the `toString()` method yet. Any suggestions on how I could override and print this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why you're intentionally trying to call a method with more elements than it can take. mets is defined exactly as the ProjectAccount toString method, which takes no parameters. The myWork class doesn't extend ProjectAccount, so how can its toString method in any way override the ProjectAccount implementation?

Comment: So rather than trying to override and pass the modified arguments, can I access the variables and modify their values and directly and call the same `toString()` method?

Comment: When using reflection as you do, you cannot change the signature of any of the methods - you can only invoke them as they are defined. So ProjectAccount method toString() will always not take any parameters. If you want it to take more parameters, your options are: 1) write another toString method within Project Account, that takes parameters (you can leave the previous toString() method as-is, just add another new one); 2) make ProjectAccount to extend myWork - which will allow you to use the myWork version of toString with parameters.

Comment: I added a solution for the second option - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified the `mywork.java` class to access the `ProjectAccount.java` class variables directly and set them.

I accessed the declared fields and based on the name or the type of the variable I modified the declared variables and called the same `toString()` method without overriding the `toString()` method.

**mywork.java**

```
package relive;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class answer_a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("relive.ProjectAccount");
            Constructor<?> constr = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(null);
            Method mets = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("toString", null);
            Object obj = constr.newInstance(new Object[] {});

            //Print Default values
            System.out.println(mets.invoke(obj, null));

            String mod_projectAccountID= "ORPT-BT-EMP-DEV";
            double mod_budget = 2200000.0;
            int mod_noOfProjects = 20;

            //Method that accesses the Fields and modifies them with the new variables

            Field [] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            for(int y=0; y<fields.length; y++){
                fields[y].setAccessible(true);

                if(fields[y].getName() == "projectAccountID"){
                    fields[y].set(obj, mod_projectAccountID);
                }
                else if(fields[y].getType().getSimpleName() == "double"){
                    fields[y].set(obj, mod_budget);
                }
                else if (fields[y].getType().getSimpleName() == "int"){
                    fields[y].set(obj, mod_noOfProjects);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(mets.invoke(obj, null));

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Answer (score -3):

there are a few issues in there.

1. overriding toString is through defining an instance method (yours is static)
2. your reflective access is with `mets` ,which references the `ProjectAccount` class
3. `mywork` is not a subclass of `ProjectAccount`
4. you can't add parameters,

> The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed. The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

```
package de.me.example;

public class SuperType {

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "SuperType";
    }

}


package de.me.example;

public class SubType extends SuperType {

    // this annatotion is syntactic sugar nothing more,
    //it behaves the same without it
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SubType";
    }

}
```

Comment: In that case, am I to declare the method inside the same try{} block and add an @Override? Can you please show an example based on this. Thanks

Comment: could you clarify, what your actually trying to get ? i understood, that you wanna overide a toString appending method parameters ?